# Latitude and Longitude validation in windows application

Tags: regex, winforms

i am searching for latitude and and longitude validation.

can any one suggest that validation.

i am using

```
if (Regex.IsMatch(textBox1.Text, "\b(?(?:90|(?:[0-8]?\\d))([ -/])[0-5]?\\d\\1[0-5]?\\d(\\.\\d{1,4})?\\1[NS])\b") == true)
```

Thanks to all.

Comment: At first glance the regex looks OK, given that your users don't try to enter the degrees symbol and are entering using degrees / minutes / seconds. What's the problem you're finding? What would you like to do?

Comment: But it is not working in windows application.

Comment: People really write "== true" in their code?  Why?

Answer (score 6):

It doesn't make sense to validate a string, these are numbers.  Convert to a number first:

```
  bool ValidateLongtitude(string txt) {
    double value;
    if (!double.TryParse(txt, out value)) return false;
    return value >= -180 && value <= 180;
  }
```

Comment: Yes this is answer.
Thanking u.

Answer (score 1):

Check if the latitude is between +/- 90 degrees (or +/- pi/2 radians) and the longitude is between +/- 180 degrees (or +/- pi radians).

Can't really give you much more than that without more detail on exactly what validation you're talking about.

Comment: yes with in range of latitude and longitude,what u mentioned above.

Comment: Can u say how to validate those ranges?